# How to render or download the specific area using cesium in untiy

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, render, cesiumjs

I am facing a peculiar issue while working with Cesium, where objects placed in a specific location seem to disappear due to gravity and it cannot render when I navigate to another location. Additionally, the tiles in that specific area also disappear after moving to another location.

I am seeking guidance on how to address and resolve this issue. My goal is to either download the specific area or implement a solution to prevent the disappearance of objects and tiles when navigating between locations.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into how to troubleshoot and fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Please share any relevant code snippets, configuration settings, or best practices that might help resolve this issue.

Before moving the camera:

[image]

After move camera the main location tiles disapper:

[image]